# How to select button group item based on true value of another element?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a custom directive `toggle-switch`

```
<toggle-switch
    id="isModule"
    ng-model="isModule"
    type="checkbox"
    switch-active="{{ isActive }}"
    switch-on-label="Module"
    switch-off-label="Segment"
    switch-on="default"
    switch-off="default"
    switch-animate="true"></toggle-switch>
```

if `isModule` is true, then I need my button group to select "Video"

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Media Type</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <div class="btn-group">
            <label class="btn btn-default" ng-model="media.mediaType" btn-radio="0" ng-disabled="(!isModule)">Audio</label>
            <label class="btn btn-default" ng-model="media.mediaType" btn-radio="1" >Video</label>
            <label class="btn btn-default" ng-model="media.mediaType" btn-radio="2" ng-disabled="(!isModule)">Text</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What is the correct way of achieving this? I'm already able to disable the other two items (as you can see), but I don't know how to select the middle one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well for now I put a watch in the controller. Not sure I like this, but it'll do until a better solution presents it's self.

```
$scope.$watch('isModule', function (oldValue, newValue) {
    if ((oldValue != null) && newValue) {
        $scope.media.mediaType = 1;
    }
});
```